# Can “genki desu ka” also mean “Am I well?”

Tags: grammar, words, expressions, word-usage

I learnt that how are you is “genki” or “o genki des ka”, but there is no anata, so how do you know that that’s not “Am I well?”. In other words how do you distinguish 1., 2., and 3. person when no pronoun is written?

Comment: It is difficult to think of a situation where you ask yourself "Am I well?", even in English. I mean, if you were _not_ well, you would notice it right away, no need to question yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand.

Answer (score 4):

As with many things in Japanese (informal language in particular), this is based on context. If you meet someone for the first time in a while, it would make sense to ask them if they are well, rather than asking them if they think *you* look well.

- Pronouns are often dropped when it is obvious who is being refereed to.
- Unlike many other languages there is no grammatical requirement to
  include the subject in a sentence.
- You may also choose to omit pronouns if you are unsure which ones
  are appropriate to address yourself or others, especially as a beginner of Japanese.

In British English, the greeting 'Are you alright?' can be shortened to 'Alright?' and most people can understand from context without specifying a pronoun.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand.